# Eclipse Error while importing project

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to import my game which I built in cocos2dx to eclipse so I can make a APK file and publish it to the play store, when I try to import my project it gives me an error, this is the error

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2jfabs2&s=8#.VRBxHIufuh8 (click to see screenshot)

I have tried solving this problem by browsing the web but all solutions aren't clear or not related to my problem.

Comment: The error clearly states what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have the android sdk where Eclipse expects it.
Two possibilities:

- you do not have the sdk anywhere on your computer.
  Then do what follows:

  - In the Eclipse toolbar, click on "window" section, and go to the "android sdk manager".
  - It will open the manager and allows you to download the last version of the SDK Tools.
- You have the SDK somewhere on your computer but in the wrong folder, then you must find it and copy it in the expected folder (as it is said on the image you shared)